# Как сделать так, чтобы в шаблонно бинарном дереве содержались объекты пользовательского класса не разрушались,после инициализации?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Нужно сделать так, чтобы в шаблонном бинарном дереве содержались объекты пользовательского класса `T` и не разрушались после инициализации. Добавление в дерево осуществляется через функцию, где и создаются элементы дерева:

```
template <class T>
void Switch(T field)
{
    ExceptionInput *e = new ExceptionInput();
    Tree<T>* tree = new Tree<T>();
    tree->Add(field);
    char answer;
    int     c, i=0;
    T field1;
    do {
        system("cls");
        cout << "Input number of method" << endl;
        cout << "1.Add" << endl;
        cout << "2.Delete one element" << endl;
        cout << "3.Look for node(return node)" << endl;
        cout << "4.Search element(return true/false)" << endl;
        cout << "5.Delete tree" << endl;
        cout << "6.Show" << endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
        do {
            cin>>c ;
            if (c > 6 || c <= 0)
                cout <<"number must be >0 and <7"<<endl;
        } while (c > 6 || c <= 0);

        switch (c)
        {
        case 1:
            if (i != 0)
            {
              cout << "input field" << endl;
               cin >> field1;
            }
            if(cin)
            tree->Add(field1); 
            else cout << "Error." <<" Field must be type of "<< (char *) typeid(field).name()<< endl;
                break;
        case 2:
            if (i != 0)
            {
                cout << "input field" << endl;
                cin >> field1;
            }
            if (cin)
            tree->Delete(field1);
            else cout << "Error." << " Field must be type of " << (char *) typeid(field).name() << endl;
            break;
        case 3:
            if (i != 0)
            {
                cout << "input field" << endl;
                cin >> field1;
            }
            if (cin)
            tree->LookForNode(tree->GetRoot(), field);
            else 
                cout << "Error." << " Field must be type of " << (char *) typeid(field).name() << endl;
            break;
        case 4:
            if (i != 0)
            {
                cout << "input field" << endl;
                cin >> field1;
            }
            if (cin)
            cout<<tree->Search(field1); 
            else 
                cout << "Error." << " Field must be type of " << (char *) typeid(field).name() << endl; 
            break;
        case 5:tree->Delete(); break;
        case 6:tree->Show(); break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(1000,'\n');
        i++;
        cout<<endl<<"Switch continue(y/n)" << endl;
        cin >> answer;
    } while (answer == 'y');
}
```

Comment: А теперь то же самое, но медленно и по-русски :) Может, хоть какой пример кода приведете для пояснения?

Comment: В чём именно ваш вопрос? `Нужно сделать...`? `Как сделать, чтобы объекты не разрушались после инициализации`? Или `где и создаются элементы дерева`?

Comment: Как сделать, чтобы объекты не разрушались после инициализации?

Comment: @Nikita, сосредоточся. Какие объекты? Как ты понял что они "разрушауься после инициалищации"? Как ты используешь `Switch`?

Comment: Обькты пользовательского класса,я это понял,потому что в конструкторах и деструкторах есть cout,который пишет,что сработал деструктор или конструктор,а Switch,я вызываю в мэйне куда и передаю,свои обьекты.

Comment: Речь идет об объектах типа `T`?

Comment: Да,именно о них

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предположу, что вы видите удаление временных объектов. Это зависит от функции `Add` вашего дерева, то есть если она объявлена не вот так:

```
bool Tree::Add(const T & element)
{
    // добавление нового узла
}
```

А вот так:

```
bool Tree::Add(T element)
{
    // добавление нового узла
}
```

То при каждом вызове `Add` будет создаваться временная копия исходного `field` под именем `element`, а потом после завершения функции еще и удаляться. Возможно поэтому вы видите трассировку вызовов конструкторов и деструкторов.

На самом же деле ваша проблема легко решается в отладчике.